# How to model your pub/sub topics name for future versioning

Tags: java, apache-kafka

We are using kafka topics in the classic way.

Many times we found ourself in a need to update our topic consumers due to the json modification or consumer change logic. so what we do:

we version our topics e.g **my_topic_v1**.

Now when some modification happens e.g json changes, consumer logic changes we upgrade the topic into v2 and we need to release new producer/consumer as well (so it can broadcast to v2 and the new versioned consumer will consume from v2)

Thats of course adding huge overheard to our devops infra and the whole syncing thing (adding producer before consumer and vice versa) as this is real-time system we cannot afford leg

Any other suggestions how to do this better ? as we think we are not doing it all right

Thanks

Comment: Well, you could just stop using JSON and use a format that actually supports upgrades within the same topic/serializer logic like Avro or Protobuf. Otherwise, losing all existing data to move to a new topic just adds overhead on everyone

Comment: @cricket_007 found some possible issue using Avro and created dedicated question please take a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432184/how-to-use-kafka-schema-management-and-avro-for-breaking-changes

Answer (score 1):

Try to have topics name as `<topicname>.<version>`.

eg. `mytopic.ver1`

Producer end will be affected during a release as data would be pushed to new topic post-release while the consumer side can be handled by defining the topics name as a regex - `mytopic.*`.

checkout the docs - `topics.regex` - [link](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs)
[subscribe](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)