# How to use kafka schema management and Avro for breaking changes

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

kafka schema management with avro give us flexibility to backward compatibility but how do we handle breaking-changes in the scheme?

Assume Producer A publish messages M to Consumer C

assume message M has a breaking change in it's scheme (e.g name field is now splitted into first_name and last_name) and we have new scheme M-New

Now we are deploying producer A-New and Consumer C-New

problem is that until our deployment process finish we can have Producer A-new publish message M-new where Consumer C (the old one) will receive the M-new and we can lose message because of that.

So the only way to do this is to sync the deployment of new producers and consumers which is adding lots of overhead

any suggestions how to handle that?

Comment: Are you using the Schema Registry? By default, it doesn't allow non-backwards compatible breaking changes. If you have a breaking change in the topic, you can either move all consumers to the latest offset (e.g. newest schema) or to a new topic

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to have a long retention period for your topics. Then you just create a new topic for the breaking changes. All consumers can move to the new topic within the retention period without losing messages.

Comment: Over time the subscription list for the consumer group just becomes rather large, if you keep doing this, though

Comment: @cricket_007 how large subscription list for the consumer group can affect the system?

Comment: @rayman Let's say you did a subscription pattern of `topic.v\d+`, then you have hundreds of partitions on these topics and you end up eventually with `topic.v10`. You then have a consumer group trying to read from thousands of partitions, and whenever just a single partition is down, the whole group rebalances, and its the rebalances that are expensive

Answer (score 0):

> e.g name field is now splitted into first_name and last_name

The Avro definition of a "backwards compatible" schema could not allow you to add these new fields without 1) keeping the old name field 2) adding defaults to the new fields - https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/avro.html

If your Consumers upgrade their schema first, they see the old name field, continuing to be sent by old producers as well as interpreting the defaults for the new fields until the producers upgrade and start sending the new fields

If the producers upgrade first, then consumers will never see the new fields, so the producers should still send out the name field, or opt to send some garbage value that'll start intentionally breaking consumers (e.g. make the field nullable to begin with but never actually send a null, then start sending a null, while consumers assume it cannot be null)

In either case, I feel like your record processing logic has to detect which fields are available and not null or their default values.

**But**, compare that to JSON or any plain string (like CSV), and you have no guarantees of what fields should be there, if they're nullable, or what types they are (is a date a string or a long?), thus you can't guarantee what objects your clients will internally map messages into for processing... That's a larger advantage of Avro I find than compatibility rules

Personally, I find enforcing FULL_TRANSITIVE compatibility on the registry works best when you have little to no communication between your Kafka users

Comment: what if we change structure of the message object? you suggest that we shall keep the old structure and add to it the new one?

Comment: As mentioned, the Schema Registry wouldn't allow that. Are you saying you're not using it and encoding every message with its own schema? In that case, consumers could just use that schema, and would never fail to deserialize a message, it's only the logic after that which would be faulty

Comment: but what happens when the new scheme will get to the hands of old consumers? will the message be lost? our busniess cant afford to itself lost messages.

Comment: If you get a processing error, offsets aren't committed, so no data would be lost. If you can't process a record, then you need to update the consumer logic, then you bounce the application, and then it continues to process from the last consumer group offset commit...

Comment: There's a very important difference between "its stored in Kafka", therefore it's not lost, then "we've processed that message, but the result is wrong", then to "we can't process that event because it's just bad", in which case, your producers have failed to communicate changes and give adequate time to consumers to upgrade